# How to cast a typed value to generic type T?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to use Azure Redis Cache in .NET Core application. I have written a CacheHelper generic method which implements generic interface like below.

However this issue is more related to Generics.

I'm getting error while casting cache value to generic type. Is this the correct way to do? or Am i missing something? Please see the code below.

```
public class CacheHelper<T> : ICacheHelper<T>
{
    private ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;

    public CacheHelper(ICacheProvider cacheProvider)
    {
        _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
    }

    public async Task<CacheResponse<T>> GetCacheValueAsync(string key)
    {
        RedisValue value = await _cacheProvider.GetCacheDatabase().StringGetAsync(key);
        if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            return value.HasValue
            ? new CacheResponse<T>(value) //I'm getting error here cannot cast type RedisValue to type T
            : CacheResponse<T>.NoValue();
        }
        else
        {
            T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
            return value.HasValue
           ? new CacheResponse<T>(obj)
           : CacheResponse<T>.NoValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect? `value` is a `RedisValue` and the constructor expects type `T` - you will have to cast or otherwise convert.

Comment: What is `CacheResponse`? Can you link to the documentation of it?

Comment: @fredrik, yes I know i need to convert. Some of the options I tried to convert is Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)) , explicitly casting it to T like (T) value but no luck.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Its a custom written class. I wanted to format the response.

Comment: Do the reverse of when it's stored in redis?

Comment: Why didn't the `Convert.ChangeType` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in `Convert` class to your advantage here:

```
new CacheResponse<T>((T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```

Comment: How do you know `T` implements `IConvertible`? According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ChangeType_System_Object_System_Type_), this is required to make the conversion work.

Comment: It does in this case - we already know `T` is `string` once we are in this branch of the `if` statement, so this will work as expected.

Comment: `value` seems to be a `RedisValue `... `T` can be `string`, but that doesn't say `value` is convertible.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I missed that. But still, it does implement it - https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/d9a5ee7fc4f1d4daef10bce4fc33e1188d6a8db2/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisValue.cs#L13

Comment: RedisValue to String is a valid conversion, I think this should work. Let me try out.

Comment: RedisValue implements IConvertible. Thanks for point it out @Martin Zikmund. When I tried initially with Convert.ChangeType, I just tried Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T) and not (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T). that's my bad. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share one more implementation of converting RedisValue to 'T' type. RedisValue implements IConvertible interface and this interface has methods to convert the instance value to a common language runtime type. This might be helpful to someone.

```
private RedisValue GetStringInRedis(string key)
{
    var redisDb = RedisConnection.GetDatabase();

    var redisValue = redisDb.StringGet(redisKey);
    if (redisValue.HasValue)
    {
        return redisValue;
    }

    return RedisValue.Null;
 }

private T ChangeToType<T>(string key, RedisValue redisValue)
{
    if (redisValue.IsNull)
        return default(T);

    try
    {
        var sRedisValue = redisValue;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool))
        {
            var tempRedisValue = (string) redisValue;
            if (tempRedisValue.ToLower() == "true")
                sRedisValue = RedisValue.Unbox(1);
            else
                sRedisValue = RedisValue.Unbox(0);
        }

        var obj = Convert.ChangeType(sRedisValue, typeof(T));
        return (T) obj;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception($"Redis key '{key}' has invalid redis value '{redisValue}'");
    }
}

public T GetValue<T>(string key)
{
    var redisValue = GetStringInRedis(key);
    return ChangeToType<T>(key, redisValue);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you should create two different implementations if `ICacheHelper<T>` interface.
One for the `string` type that implements `ICacheHelper<string>`.
One for all other types that implements `ICacheHelper<T>`.

Comment: What has that to do with this question?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It only happened to him because he tried to do the exact same handling for `string` and `T`. You can't make this mistake if you write code to only handle `string`.

Comment: You've got a point. The entire ICacheHelper has a generic parameter, whereas you'd expect the Get() method to have one.